# error: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

each time I tried to run this query it gives this error 
1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

```
INSERT INTO `tender_request` (`Tender_Request_ID`, `Cost`, `Document`, `Status`, `supplierID`, `TenderID`) VALUES ('5556', '900', NULL, 'Active', '1', '652')
```

actually, I don't know where is the problem.
and this is my code on tender_request table:

```
  BEGIN

SET  @Ecost=( SELECT `estimated_cost` 
  FROM tender
  INNER JOIN tender_request ON `tender`.`Tender_ID`=`tender_request`.`TenderID`);

IF(@Ecost>new.Cost) then
  UPDATE `kpi` INNER JOIN tender_request on tender_request.TenderID=kpi.tenID 
set kpi.Cost=10 where TenderID=new.TenderID limit 1;
 END IF;
END
```

My first table :
Tender_request( `Tender_Request_ID`, `Cost`, `Document`, `Status`, `supplierID`, `TenderID` )

My Second table :
KPI(`KPI_ID`, `Cost`, `Delivery`, `Service`, `Quality`, `Experience`, `supID`, `tenID`)

Third table :
Tender(`Tender_ID`, `Name`, `Description`, `Estimated_cost`)

Comment: which error do you obtain? It shows a reference line?
Also, you could try with a TOP 1 instead of LIMIT 1 or include another constraint

Comment: @KPavezC OP specifically tag `MySQL`.  Why `TOP 1`???

Comment: @rozana The error couldn't be any clearer.  Your subquery returns more than 1 row, thus the error.  What else can we say???

Comment: how can I overcome the error?

Comment: @rozana . . . You should ask a new question.  Provide sample data and desired results on what you really want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
BEGIN

  SET  @Exist=( SELECT 1
  FROM tender
  INNER JOIN tender_request ON 
 `tender`.`Tender_ID`=`tender_request`.`TenderID`
  WHERE `estimated_cost`>new.Cost AND 
 `tender`.`Tender_ID`=new.TenderID Limit 1;

 IF(@Exist=1) then
    UPDATE `kpi` INNER JOIN tender_request on 
    tender_request.TenderID=kpi.tenID 
    set kpi.Cost=10 where TenderID=new.TenderID;
 END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked how many rows this query return?  I'm sure more than 1.

```
SET  @Ecost=( SELECT `estimated_cost` 
  FROM tender
  INNER JOIN tender_request ON `tender`.`Tender_ID`=`tender_request`.`TenderID`);
```

Try to add `LIMIT 1` at the end.

Comment: But out of all the `tender`, how do you know which one to get?  The `LIMIT 1` only get the first one.  Not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: It works when I add where on the select ,  `SET  @Ecost=( SELECT estimated_cost 
  FROM tender
  INNER JOIN tender_request ON tender.Tender_ID=tender_request.TenderID where tender_request.TenderID=new.TenderID);`

Comment: Can you not get the answer you want with SET @Ecost=( SELECT estimated_cost FROM tender where Tender_ID = new.TenderID)

Comment: @rozana `SET @Ecost=...` can only accept a scalar value.  So as long as your query returns just 1 value, it will work.  In this case, adding `WHERE tender_request.TenderID=new.TenderID` will limit the record to 1, so it works.  But in your example above, there no `WHERE` clause so it errors out.